# Running multiple loop at once in bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Below is the script that I am running

```sh
#!/bin/bash

region=('us-east-1' 'eu-central-1')
env=('prod' 'stage')


for region in "${region[@]}"
do
        for env in "${env[@]}"
        do
                echo "$region"
                echo "$env"
        done
done
```

The output that I am getting is

```
us-east-1
prod
us-east-1
stage
eu-central-1
stage
eu-central-1
stage
```

But my expectation was to get

```
us-east-1
prod
us-east-1
stage
eu-central-1
prod
eu-central-1
stage
```

The script should run for both env conditions, but its running only once for prod and thrice for stage.
Where am I going wrong here, any pointers or advice would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use a different variable for the loop than the initial array. Otherwise you are overwriting the array during the first iteration.

Here I'm using different variables for the array and the loop variable:

```
#!/bin/bash

regions=('us-east-1' 'eu-central-1')
envs=('prod' 'stage')
    
for region in "${regions[@]}"
do
    for env in "${envs[@]}"
    do
        echo "$region"
        echo "$env"
    done
done
```

Output:

```
us-east-1
prod
us-east-1
stage
eu-central-1
prod
eu-central-1
stage
```

---

PS: Another option would be to use a string of multiple words and have bash iterating over that:

```
for a in foo bar
do
    for b in baz qux
    do
        echo "${a}"
        echo "${b}"
    done
done
```

Comment: Thanks this is the easiest way to do that, apart from that i have included env=('prod' 'stage') within for loop of region. that also helps here

Answer (score 4):

Arrays and scalar parameters lives in the same namespace, so the scalar will override the array in this example:

```
$ a=(hello world)
$ a=123
$ echo "${a[@]}"
123
```

In your example you are overriding the `env` variable in the inner loop, the execution is the following, in pseudo code:

```
expand "${region[@]}" into 'us-east-1' 'eu-central-1'
set region 'us-east-1'
expand "${env[@]}" into 'prod' 'stage'
set env 'prod'
... echo ...
set env 'stage'
... echo ...
set region 'us-central-1'
expand "${env[@]}" into 'stage'
...
```

Consider the following:

```
$ a="hello"; echo "${a[@]}"
hello
```